# Thumbnail preview in explorer not showing thumbnails for images until vieweed by default app

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

Windows10, there are thumbnails for some images, but for some of them it does not. 
I thought in direction of `Always show icons, never thumbnails` etc, but there ARE thumbs for some images.

As an application to open images I use XnView and I found that the thumbs appear after I open the file using default windows image viewer (unsure its name in English, something like Photos or Images).

How can I generate thumbs for all images without explicitly scrolling through them using default viewer?

Comment: Does this apply to all images in all locations, or only specific files, or only those in a specific directory?

Comment: @grawity I have no videos on this PC so I didn't check it against this type. Have just checked images in another directory: works same way. If I haven't answered your question please re-word it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer tends to individualize views by folder.

Open a very top level folder with Windows Explorer, set it the way you wish with respect to views.

Then, in Windows Explorer, View Tab, Options, Folder options and get the Folder options dialog window.

Then View tab, Click on "Apply to Folders"  and then Apply.

You may have to do this a couple of times.